# Call api return an 500 error (Call to a member function isAdmin())

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, php-7.2, pimcore-v5

I'm using `lexik_jwt_authentication` to make api calls to symfony. I made the call to `login` and I get the token so all good at this level. Now when I tried to make a call to another api whith this token I get the error : `Call to a member function isAdmin() on null (500 Internal Server Error)`. My api :

```
/**
     * @Route("/vsbridge/product/get/{product}")
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @param Request           $request
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getProduct(
        Request $request
    ) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        return $this->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'result' => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

Have you an idea ? Thx in advance.

Comment: what API you are calling please recheck your URL again because if this action executing I can't see anything that you get this error

Comment: @habibun api : http://pimcore.loc/vsbridge/product/get/108

Comment: try to check duplicate URL or search by isAdmin from where it is executing.